# Does using JavaFX Dialogs require JDK8u40, or can any version be used?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I'm using the JDK8u40 for it's Dialogs in JavaFX. Will any user be able to use these with their Java version or will they require that specific version of the JRE?

Comment: The user must have a java8 jre. Not the special 40.

Comment: That is incorrect Jens - the Java version must be Java 8u40 or later.  The JavaFX Dialog class to be introduced in Java8u40 will not work with an earlier Java release such as Java8u31 because the class does not exist in the earlier Java releases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will require 8u40. It is mean that you should provide 8u40 JRE as part of your installation package (DMG, MSI, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

They will require that specific version of the JRE.